# What means that a pendulum system having saddle points?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What means that a pendulum system having saddle points? I know when it haves drain, source but I can't find any information of when it has saddle points

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking about the saddle points in the phase portrait?

Comment: Yes!! tha'ts it

Comment: OK, but I still don't get what you're asking. In the phase portrait the saddle points are just the unstable equilibria i.e. when the pendulum is balanced above the pivot point. Have you studied the phase portrait? If not, lots of articles on it are a mere Google away.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply put: a saddle point is an unstable equilibrium. Without solving the equations, you can probably guess where there is an unstable equilibrium for a simple pendulum system: if the pendulum is above right the pivot, it will stay there. But give it even a the slightest notch, and it will not go back to this position.

In contrast, when the pendulum hangs straight down, and you give it a small push, it will restabilise. This is a stable equilibrium.